# Android In-app Billing - Receiving IN_APP_NOTIFY only once

Tags: android, in-app-billing, notify

In the [In-App Billing Overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html), it is stated that the app should send a CONFIRM_NOTIFICATIONS message to acknowledge the purchase, and in the absence of this, Google Play would repeatedly send IN_APP_NOTIFY messages. However, I happen to only receive it once.

But when I do a new purchase, I also receive notifications for other pending purchases (I have 3 IN_APP_NOTIFY per purchase, 2 of them seem to be for previous products). Which mean that my purchases are not acknowledged and thus it works as expected. But then, why do I not receive IN_APP_NOTIFY messages periodically? Is there something special to do?

Thanks in advance!